# OpenGL/C++ complication. Deconstructor/Constructer Var Error

Tags: c++, opengl, constructor, destructor, glut

I am creating a class named Square and functions to calculate x,y,z position to create 4 vertex to render a square in OpenGL.

Errors

```
8       [Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token
8       [Error] expected `,' or `;' before '.' token
9       [Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token
9       [Error] expected `,' or `;' before '.' token
```

Here is the main.cpp

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Square2D.h"
SquareD Love;
Love.SetOrigin(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
Love.CalcVert(2.0f);

void Display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Switch to the drawing perspective
glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective
Love.RenderSquare();
glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
glutSwapBuffers();
};

void reshape(int w, int h) 
{
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the camera
gluPerspective(45.0,(double)w/(double)h,1.0,200.0);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//Init
glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
//Create Window
glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(40,40);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGLUT Shapes");
//OpenGL Enables for effects
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
//Functions
glutDisplayFunc(Display);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
//Main OpenGL loop
glutMainLoop();
//Return success//C++ requirement
return 0;
}
```

Here is the SquareD class
Header file

```
#ifndef XYZSQUARE_H
#define XYZSQUARE_H
// No description
class SquareD
{
public:
    // class constructor
    SquareD();
    // class destructor
    ~SquareD();

    void SetOrigin(float X,float Y,float Z);
    void RenderSquare();
    void CalcVert(float lenght);

    private:
    float TL_X,TL_Y,TL_Z;
    float TR_X,TR_Y,TR_Z;
    float BL_X,BL_Y,BL_Z;
    float BR_X,BR_Y,BR_Z;
    float Lenght;
    float OriginX,OriginY,OriginZ;
    };
    #endif // SQUARE_H
```

The .cpp file for the SquareD class

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "Square2D.h" // class's header file
// class constructor
SquareD::SquareD()
{
// insert your code here
}
// class destructor
SquareD::~SquareD()
{
// insert your code here
}
void SquareD::SetOrigin(float X,float Y,float Z)
{
    OriginX=X;//X
    OriginY=Y;//Y
    OriginZ=Z;//Z
};
void SquareD::CalcVert(float lenght)
{
 Lenght=lenght/2;
 //Left Front
 TL_X =OriginX-Lenght;//X
 TL_Y =OriginY;       //Y
 TL_Z =OriginZ+Lenght;//Z
 //Right Front
 TR_X =OriginX+Lenght;//X
 TR_Y =OriginY;       //Y
 TR_Z =OriginZ+Lenght;//Z
 //Left Back
 BL_X =OriginX-Lenght;//X
 BL_Y =OriginY;       //Y
 BL_Z =OriginZ-Lenght;//Z
 //Right Back
 BR_X =OriginX+Lenght;//X
 BR_Y=OriginY;       //Y
 BR_Z=OriginZ-Lenght;//Z
};
void SquareD::RenderSquare()
{
     glVertex3f(TL_X,TL_Y,TL_Z);
 glVertex3f(TR_X,TR_Y,TR_Z);
 glVertex3f(BL_X,BL_Y,BL_Z);
 glVertex3f(BR_X,BR_Y,BR_Z);
};
```

What is causing the error and why?

Comment: Your approach is engineering overkill. Maybe good for learning things, but certainly not something you'd want to have in a serious program.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.

Firstly, you can not call functions like that (out of context). If you call the functions in main, then it will work :

```
int main()
{
  Love.SetOrigin(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  Love.CalcVert(2.0f);
  // rest of code
  // ...
}
```

Second, you need to call `glBegin`/`glEnd` when rendering :

```
void SquareD::RenderSquare()
{
  glBegin( GL_QUADS );
     glVertex3f(TL_X,TL_Y,TL_Z);
     glVertex3f(TR_X,TR_Y,TR_Z);
     glVertex3f(BL_X,BL_Y,BL_Z);
     glVertex3f(BR_X,BR_Y,BR_Z);
  glEnd();
};
```

If you calculated your vertices correctly, and if you set the view port correctly, and you set rest correctly, you should see a square.